# What would be the best way to add Performance Testing in Continuous Integration/Delivery Environment

Tags: jmeter, continuous-integration, performance-testing, load-testing, continuous-deployment

I'm about to integrate performance testing on CI, but I'm having a hard time to decide which ones I should execute and how to run it:

1. Should I run load testing on individual APIs or should I run the whole workflow (e.g.: `Login -> Home Page -> Search`)
2. How long I should run it?
3. Should I also add stress, peak and soak testing?
   I'm thinking, those should be run out of the CI.

Any comments would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main idea of including tests in continuous integration process is protecting yourself from [regressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_regression), i.e. to ensure that a new feature or a bug fix doesn't cause performance degradation.

So common practice is to have short-term [Load Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load_testing) covering essential features and conducting anticipated number of users to be run periodically (i.e. on each commit or [pull request](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-request-pull) to master/integration branch).

If you have enough capacity and environment availability it would also make sense to have [soak test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soak_testing) in place, but it should occur less frequently (you want to keep build time short enough, don't you?), i.e. overnight or over the weekend. This way you will be able to identify possible [memory leaks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak)

Both approaches assume having some reference metrics collected by previous ad-hoc runs which can be considered as acceptable pass/fail criteria.

[Stress test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress_testing) assumes identifying saturation/breaking points so normally it is not included into CI pipeline and being run manually before major releases.

Check out [How to Include Load Testing in your Continuous Integration Environment](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-include-load-testing-your-continuous-integration-environment-0) article for more information.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to say what you should test without knowing what's important to your application. In many applications, testing the performance of login would be less important than testing the performance of search and a sub-optimal use of time. However getting an accurate performance of search against test data can be challenging, but hardly impossible. If running on CI, one could develop scripts that test performance in a critical or often changing area. Your CI system could be setup to watch for changes in these areas and then kick off the performance tests if necessary. When done, CI could notify the developer if the performance in an area where he or she made changes doesn't meet a specified threshold. I'd worry about running a few mission-critical performance tests with a tight feedback loop rather than worrying about running many types of tests. Remember, someone has to maintain these tests and supporting infrastructure.

Answer (score 0):

If your developers are committing code continuously and have concerns on large load tests running for every single commit, you can ask them to batch the commits and trigger the build for performance test phase at a later time. However, all the interim builds can be allowed to go through the full QA cycle if the QA phase is well optimized and can finish within minutes. A 10-15 minute period is a good interval for a build to complete full automated tests.  Now, the pipeline should mark them as interim builds that are not production ready and should allow them only after the completion of all the performance tests. You can also extend it by short load tests that match with the CI QA tests but defer the larger load tests to end-of day. In summary, the production deployment for the build has to wait until the load and soak tests have been completed. It does limit your ability to deploy several times throughout the day without risk. IF you would rather prefer to accept a certain degree of risk, you can proceed to deploy for minor changes like property and configuration changes.